# how to capture timestamp with milliseconds in ssis package 2016

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, ssis-2016

How to capture current timestamp in ssis package 2016

I declared a  variable and using expression but milliseconds are missing

```
@currenttimestamp = (DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)@[System::StartTime]
```

I want the milliseconds too

Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to use the below answer with @[System::StartTime], as it returns .000 in milliseconds place

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved when casting to `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,3)`:

```
(DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,3)GETDATE()
```

but the time get changes as it  using the getdate() asit returns the current time, I need the package start time I used the following

```
(DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,3)@[System::StartTime]
```

but the milliseconds is coming as .000

Do i have to use the getdate() in ExecuteSQLTask and assign that value to a string variable. I am new to ssis please give suggestions.

Comment: I used the ExecuteSQLTask but here also it storing only the datetime without milliseconds

Comment: You shouldn't ask a new, or followup, question in an answer and expect to get responses.  You should either post a new question, or delete this answer and edit your existing question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below comand in the Execute SQL Task at the begining of the package that will give you the exact start time of the package.

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as datetime2(6)) 'Date';
```

Comment: I want the whole date time including the milliseconds not just milliseconds

Comment: Then you can add GetDate in the SQL statement of the Execute SQL task and later concate the both columns by converting them into String type.