# how to capture Package start time with milliseconds in ssis package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016

I want the package start time including milliseconds, in the below code I am using @[System::StartTime] but have milliseconds like this .000 no numbers are displaying

```
(DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,3)@[System::StartTime]
```

How to get the package start time with milliseconds?

---

Edit

I am getting milliseconds in this code (DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,3)GETDATE() but the problem is GETDATE() returns only the current time not the starting time. How to execute this code at the start and assign the value to another variable

Comment: When I used ExecuteSQLTask and used SELECT GETDATE then I also not getting the milliseconds but in SQL server I am getting the milliseconds

Comment: I am getting milliseconds in this code (DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,3)GETDATE() but the problem is GETDATE() returns only the current time not the starting time. How to execute this code at the start and assign the value to another variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to capture Package start time with milliseconds in ssis package 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104035/how-to-capture-package-start-time-with-milliseconds-in-ssis-package-2016)

Answer (score 0):

I used an ExecuteSQLTask and used the following code

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as datetime2(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL comand in Execute SQL task at the begining of the package.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)+'.'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATEPART(MS,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to be able to use the package start time in multiple places, have millisecond precision, and have it always be the same value. So, I have started creating a user variable and binding its value in an Expression Task like so:

```
@[User::PackageStartLiteral] =
"cast('" +

(DT_WSTR, 4)datepart("YEAR", GetDate()) + "-" + 
right("00" + (DT_WSTR, 4)datepart("MONTH", GetDate()), 2) + "-" + 
right("00" + (DT_WSTR, 4)datepart("DAY", GetDate()), 2) + "T" + 
right("00"+(DT_WSTR,2) datepart("hour", GetDate()), 2) + ":" + 
right("00"+ (DT_WSTR,2) datepart("minute", GetDate()), 2)+ ":" + 
right("00"+ (DT_WSTR,2) datepart("second", GetDate()), 2) + "." +
right("000"+ (DT_WSTR,3) datepart("millisecond", GetDate()), 3) + 

"' AS datetime)"
```